# Checkbox checked attribute not toggling

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, checked

I came across a strange issue when attempting to add jQuery functionality initiated by a checkbox. My checkbox appears to be toggling the checked attribute, since visually the check mark toggles on click, but the "checked" attribute actually never changes.

Here's an example of my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ez710gxL/3/

```
<input id="check_box_2" class="css-checkbox padding-left-3" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<label for="check_box_2" name="cb_lbl_2" class="css-label" style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:10px;">Show Note</label>
```

My question is:
If the checked attribute does not change, how can I use jQuery to determine if the checkbox is checked or not?

Comment: Did you forget to add the jQuery to your demo, or is it purely an HTML issue of some sort?

Comment: look on forked fiddle: to check checkbox state use .prop() method http://jsfiddle.net/143Lyhxo/ as @dave stated in his answer

Comment: Sorry @DavidThomas, I did forget to add the jQuery to the demo. I have updated it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ez710gxL/3/

Comment: `$('#check_box_2').is(':checked')`...

Comment: @War10ck that test does not work since the property never changes, although the checkbox appears to check/uncheck.

Comment: @ericbelldesigns It does work http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/ez710gxL/4/. When you manually check/uncheck the box, the property value is changed by the browser...

Comment: @War10ck actually, even though the property doesn't change, that test does work.

Comment: @ericbelldesigns That's because the browser's DOM object for this input is updated behind the scenes. Once the attribute is read in on page load, it's not updated automatically with the user interaction. In this case, think of it as a default value. Once an interaction occurs, the default value is no longer relevant...

Comment: @War10ck thank you so much for your suggestions, and especially the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so apparently the issue was not with the prop/attr toggling "checked", but rather the property updating when viewing the browser's developer tools. When I inspect the checkbox, the checked property ALWAYS stays "checked", however the following code works to determine if the checkbox is actually checked or not (@War10ck's suggested code):

```
$('#check_box_2').is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Set the `.prop("checked", true)`. This is one of the greatest benefits of `.prop()` over `.attr()` since `.prop()` can set values that are non-strings.

Here's a working example on how to use it:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  if ($("#chkBox1").prop("checked"))
    $("#chkBox1").prop("checked", false);
  else
    $("#chkBox1").prop("checked", true);
  }, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="Test" id="chkBox1" checked />
```

Comment: you must be have a crystal globe

Comment: Let's see your code. There is no javascript or jQuery in your fiddle. You can see in my example above how it works

Comment: Here's my updated code with jQuery included: http://jsfiddle.net/ez710gxL/3/. You can see when I click '.css-label' and use the same logic you have, the checked property/attribute does not change.

Comment: Your code is working as expected. If you click the text "Show Activity" or "Show Pictures" those both will uncheck the checkbox next to the "Show Note" label. The problem you are having is that your label has a `for` attribute. This means when you click the label, treat is the same as if that target is clicked, so that behavior is conflicting with your jQuery code. I'm not sure what you are actually trying to accomplish but you may not need the jQuery.

Comment: @dave thank you! I was just trying to determine if it was checked or not, so my issue is solved. I was really just confused since the property was not updated onclick in Developer Tools.